# Linux Java Application Memory Leak Detection

Tags: java, linux, memory, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have a spring application which loads a lot of data from S3 and pushes to RedShift. I have hosted this on a machine with 64GB of RAM. The first time the deployment is done, the available free memory when I run the free command is 44 GB.

[image]

Next day when i run the same command, the free memory would reduce to 30 GB and so on. I get a lot of .hprof files in the /tmp directory and I want to find out the reason for this free memory reduction. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: How much memory does the JVM think it is allowed to use

Comment: The Xmx and Xms are set to 4 GB

Comment: Attach jvisualvm to see what is going on.

Answer (score -1):

A good tool for finding memory leaks is JConsole. Full documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html)

You should also look out the code of your application, which objects are instantiated and remain there (singletons for example). Remember that all the references that a singleton has will never be freed by the garbage collector.

I would also check if any of the libraries that you are using might have some memory leak issue.